# Python how to create a document matrix with (i,j) entries being term index

Tags: python, numpy, text, data-manipulation, lda

I run into the following issues with text data matrix manipulation.

I have the original text document as well, stored in a list. Below is an example for the first element of the list of text data.

```
text_data[1]
u"\n The Bechtel Group Inc. offered in 1985 to sell oil to Israel at a 
discount of at least 650 million for 10 years if it promised not to 
bomb a proposed Iraqi pipeline, a Foreign Ministry official said 
Wednesday. But then-Prime Minister Shimon Peres said the offer from 
Bruce Rappaport, a partner in the San Francisco-based construction and 
engineering company, was ``unimportant,'' the senior official told The 
Associated Press. Peres, now foreign minister, never discussed the 
offer with other government ministers, said the official, who spoke on 
condition of anonymity.
```

I hope to get a matrix where x_{ij} indicates term-index of the j-th poisitioned word in the i-th document. An example would be the following:

```
 Words W = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]) # word indices for a dictionary of words

 # D := document words X = np.array([
   [0, 0, 1, 2, 2], # e.g., this row means 1st, and 2nd position is the first term in the dictionary, etc.
   [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 2, 2, 2],
   [4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
   [3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
   [3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
   ])
```

What I can think of is to first create a dictionary for terms in the corpus and have their corresponding index. Then go through each document, iterate through the whole documents, and put the term index for a word appearing in document i and position j. But this seems very lengthy and inefficient.

Comment: That looks hard to me as the first matrix doesn't give you information of the positions of the words? I guess the only thing you can do is parse the text document again.

Comment: sorry, i should have mentioned that I have the original documents too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a similar challenge a few months ago. I'm pretty sure there is a way to do it using Python NLTK. Googling "corpus to term count vectors" should get you a good start.

I ended up just implementing my own though, as you suggest in your question.

```py
def document_to_term_counts(document, vocab):
    term_count = [0] * len(vocab)
    for word in document:
        if word in vocab:
            term_count[vocab.index(word)] += 1
    return term_count

def count_words_in_documents(documents):
    word_counts = {}
    for document in documents:
        words_found_in_document = set()
        for word in document:
            if word not in word_counts:
                word_counts[word] = {'all_appearances': 1, 'document_appearances': 1}
            else:
                word_counts[word]['all_appearances'] += 1
                if word not in words_found_in_document:
                    word_counts[word]['document_appearances'] += 1
            words_found_in_document.add(word)
    return word_counts

def word_counts_to_vocab(word_counts, min_document_apperances, max_document_apperances):
    vocab = []
    for word in word_counts:
        document_apperances = word_counts[word]['document_appearances']
        if document_apperances >= min_document_apperances and document_apperances <= max_document_apperances:
            vocab.append(word)
    return vocab

def documents_to_vocab(documents, min_document_apperances, max_document_apperances):
    word_counts = count_words_in_documents(documents)
    vocab = word_counts_to_vocab(word_counts, min_document_apperances, max_document_apperances)

    return vocab

documents = [
    ['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumped'],
    ['foxes', 'are', 'quick']
]

vocab = documents_to_vocab(documents, 1, 100)
print('vocabulary:')
print(vocab)

for document in documents:
    term_counts = document_to_term_counts(document, vocab)
    print('-'*50)
    print(document)
    print(term_counts)
```

[my full project](https://github.com/alex9311/alex9311.github.io/tree/master/code-projects/game-of-thrones-lda)